# How to insert 3 divs on the same line

Tags: html, line

I try to insert 2 divs on the same line and isn't woring.The last div is always placed on the bottom of the page.

Here's the CSS:

```
 #content1
   { 
  background-image:url(html/images/content1.png);
width: 23.4%;
height: 100%; 
margin-top: 9%;
margin-left: 0;
 padding-bottom: 5%;
}
.middle_menu
{
list-style-type:none;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size:13px;
 color:#BDBDBD;
text-decoration:none;
padding: 5%;
  }
  #chat_menu
 { 
background-image:url(html/images/content1.png);
 width: 23.4%;
height: 100%; 
margin-top: 1%;
 margin-left: 0;
 }
#chat
{
 padding-top: 2%;
 padding-bottom: 2%;
    margin-left: 2.5%;
  }
   #content2
  { 
  background-image:url(html/images/content2.jpg);
  width: 70%;
    height: 100%; 
   margin-top: 1%;
   margin-left: 0;
    }
```

And here's the HTML:

```
<div id="content1">
                <ul class="middle_menu">
            <li><a href="index.html" >Naruto Shippuden Ep. 313</a></li>                                                                                                                                                                                                         
            <li><a href="index.html" >Strike Witches Ep. 8</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" >Sword Art Online Ep. 24</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html" >Baccano! Ep. 8</a></li>
        </ul>
                </div>
    <div id="chat_menu">
                <div id="chat">"Here's a online chat script"</div>                    
            </div>
    <div id="content2"  style="float: right;"> 
        <img src="html/images/2.png" align="center" valign="center">
        </div>
```

So there are two divs placed in the left side of the page one over another and i want to put the third div called "content2" on the same line with these two.
I would be very grateful if someone can help me.

Comment: well, your widths don't add up. 23.4 + 23.4 + 70 = 116.8%. plus, you've only floated the `content2` div, so `content1` is going to go onto its own line no matter WHAT you try.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Add a wrapper `<div>` around the other `<div>`s.  Give the wrapper a style of `position: relative`.
2. Add the following to the style for #content2: `position:absolute; top:0; right:0;`
3. Get rid of the `style="float:right;"` on #content2
4. Fix the width on #content2 to be something that will fit, as Marc B suggested.

See [JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/WeTEp/).